# post endpoint 404 in firefox and pending in chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, pg

Following this quick guide ([React and PostgreSQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oAS7MtMwqA)), the following app should print the JSON fetch to the bash terminal (at ~37min of video).

However this does not happen. There is no feedback on the npm or nodemon servers.

When adding a value via the front-end, firefox instantly sends back a 404 status (observed in console:network). In chrome, the thread hangs as pending until the nodemon server is shut down (and then fails with a connection reset error)(again in console:network).

npm is running app and nodemon is running the server.

> app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super();  
        this.state = {
          title: 'Simple postgres app',
          treatments: []
        }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
        console.log('COMPONENT HAS MOUNTED')
  }   

  addStuff(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    // console.log('in method');

    let data = {
            test_field: this.refs.test_field.value,
    };

    var request = new Request('http://localhost:3000/api/new-thing', {
            method: 'POST', 
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
            body: JSON.stringify(data), 
            message: console.log('JSON output: ', JSON.stringify(data))
    }); 

    fetch(request)
      .then((response) => {
        response.json()
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
          })
      })
  }

  render() {
    let title = this.state.title;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1> { title } </h1>  
        <form ref = "testForm">
                        <input type="text" ref="test_field" placeholder="test_field"/> 
                        <button onClick={this.addStuff.bind(this)}>Add This</button>
                </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

> server.js

```
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let morgan = require('morgan');
let pg = require('pg');
const PORT = 3000;

// let pool = new pg.Pool({
//         port: 5432,
//         user: 'postgres',
//         password: 'postgres',
//         database: 'po1dev_v0.0.1',
//         max: 10, //max connections
//         host: 'localhost'
// })

let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true }));

app.use(morgan('dev')); 

app.use((request, response, next) => {
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
});   

// app.post('/api/new-thing', (request,response) => {
//     console.log(request.body)
// })
app.post('/api/new-thing', function(request,response){
    console.log(request.body);
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Listening on port ' + PORT));
```

Any ideas on what may be causing the 404/hang problems in firefox/chrome and how to go about fixing it?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the route you're creating doen't return any response so it waits indefinitely for a response then gets timed out.

The route should return some response,

```
app.post('/api/new-thing', function(request,response){
    console.log(request.body);
    return response.json({"data": "Hello World"})
})
```

Which will return the `{"data": "Hello World"}` from the `/api/new-thing` route.

Also, `bodyParser.json` is a function not property. Change it to

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

If you are using `create-react-app` try another port for the backend server. Because by default it uses 3000 for the react app.

Comment: There must be something else wrong. Adding a response to app.post still results in an instant new-thing 404 in firefox, new-thing pending in chrome and no output on the nodemon server

Comment: What is the result when you hit HTTP POST `http://localhost:3000/api/new-thing` from postman or something?

Comment: Nothing. More specifically it just displays the 'Loading...' message. I guess that means there is something wrong with the endpoint setup(?)
Edit: it just came back with 'Could not get any response'. So a timeout as you suggested

Comment: I think I figured it out. if you used `create-react-app` then the default port for the react app is at `3000`, also you are using the backend server port at `3000` as well. Can you change the backend port to maybe 3001 and then check `http://localhost:3001/api/new-thing`

Comment: I did indeed use create-react-app. Changing the request port and the server ports to 3001 stops the 404 error. Upon button press, in firefox, an 'options' method returns a status 204 and the 'post' method hangs. The same behaviour is observed in chrome. There is no feedback from nodemon (console.log(request.body)) on port 3001.

Comment: edited the answer, use `bodyParser.json()` not `bodyParser.json`

Comment: FMFL....it seems I've become too reliant on the linters and whatnot to catch incorrect coding and in this case it did not pick it up. Could you give a lay explanation of why having the front and backends running on the same port causes issues? Edit: wish I could upvote you for getting me back on my feet :)

Comment: Because the front end server is basically a http server (webpack dev server) that runs on 3000 port. So, the port is already bound to that http server instance. So, any other process cannot bind itself to that 3000 server as it is already being used. That's basically it. you can check [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0) for how to use package.json proxy which will be usefull in your case.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the extra effort and info :)